# Entity Framework MySQL для существующей бд

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Есть приложение для учета магазина, которое работает с mysql на хостинге. Бд уже довольно большая и ее структура продолжает дорабатываться. Писал приложение до этого на запросах, хочу попробовать юзать EF. Подскажите,  есть ли способ сгенерировать структуру существующей бд в коде?

Comment: Описываете ваши таблицы в виде классов и прописываете `add migration *someName*`. Ниже полезные ссылки, в т.ч. на видео по демонстрации, как пользоваться этим https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/3.12.php https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-migration.aspx https://youtu.be/2PW3fLc_qeM

Comment: видимо тебе надо вот это - https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/1.3.php - создание классов на основе бд

Comment: Официальная документация: [Reverse Engineering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding?tabs=dotnet-core-cli). Вот ещё: [Get started with EF Database First](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database). И другой ресурс: [Creating a Model for an Existing Database](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/create-model-for-existing-database-in-ef-core.aspx)